# Meaning of "racial lines"

Tags: proper-nouns

Here's part of an [article](https://econ.st/2HllkOR):

> The bleakest charge, heard in political speeches, in academic discourse and from community campaigners, is that American schools and neighbourhoods are resegregating along "racial lines", in mockery of King's legacy. (the last sentence of paragraph 4th)

I suppose the "charge" here means accusation or criticism. So do the "racial lines" here have the same meaning of "a colour line" mentioned earlier in the middle of paragraph 3rd? Do they mean an actual line separating the then black and white races for some services like transportation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no literal line being proposed here.  The phrase "along racial lines" is frequently used to mean "separated by race" even if there's no physical separation.  In the quoted article, it refers to "schools and neighborhoods" being resegregated **along racial lines**, which means that fewer schools and neighborhoods are racially integrated - blacks live in one neighborhood and whites live in another.  Likewise, each race is attending different schools. Maybe you could draw a neat line on the map showing the different neighborhoods, but that is not necessarily the case.

Here's another example of this phrase being used with absolutely no connotation physical separation:

> Chief Justice Sundaresh Menon, who is chairing the Commission, asked if the system could give the process a nudge "once in a while", perhaps until Singapore reaches an ideal stage where people do not vote **along racial lines**.

[ From [Channel NewsAsia](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/singapore/do-people-vote-along-racial-lines-the-constitutional-commission--8103098) ]

Again, there are no physical lines here: it just means that most voters of a particular race are choosing to vote for candidates based on sharing the same race as that candidate.

A similar phrase you will see is **along party lines**.  If I say that a law was passed in the US Congress **along party lines**, then it means that all (or almost all) of the Republicans voted "yes" and all of the Democrats voted "no". In this case, the definition of [**line**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line) that is being referenced is, "an official or public position," meaning the official position of the political party.

I suspect that **along party lines** was the original idiom, and **along racial lines** was created as an analogy to that.